# MySql.Data.MySqlClient namespace vs System.Data.OracleClient Namespace

Tags: c#, mysql, vb.net, oracle

That is the first time that I`m working with oracle database and not MS-SQL.
I discovered that there are 2 namespaces that I can reference in my project in order to connect and manipulate oracle database.

MySql.Data.MySqlClient namespace and System.Data.OracleClient Namespace.

Very clear that MySql.Data.MySqlClient was written by oracle and  System.Data.OracleClient by microsoft, but couldent find any comparison on the net.

Because their objectives and functionality is quite similar I feel the need to ask, from your experience, which one of them should I focus on? Are there any main differences?

Comment: `MySQL` is for MySQL which was acquired by Oracle.  They are bound to be similar since they all inherit from the `System.Data.Common` types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither.

Oracle has made its own [NET Provider](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) (ODP.NET) and you should use it.
The [OracleClient namespace is deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7(v=vs.110).aspx). It has been built by Microsoft in the first days of NET.Framework to support one of the most important database in the enterprise market. As of today, there is no real reason for Microsoft to continue its development when you can get the official one built directly by Oracle.

MySql is a different database and its provider ([NET.Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)) could not work with an Oracle database. Yes, the work pattern is identical (like every other NET provider should, because all derive from the same base classes) but its internal code cannot really talk to an Oracle database. (Never tried though)

Comment: they say: "ODP.NET makes using Oracle from .NET more flexible, faster, and more stable" i guess i have no choice but to believe them (-: